# Determining whether a group of spatially extensive data is centered around one point in space

Tags: data-visualization, spatial, continuous-data

Consider a single x axis representing points along a line in space. I've got a set of data (in this case the receptive fields of hippocampal place cells recorded as a rat runs along a linear track), which are themselves spatially extensive, ie. if displayed graphically against the axis they would look like a series of horizontal bars, distributed at different points along the axis.

---

```
  ____   
 ____
           ____ fields
```

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_____axis

What I want to do is to define a point of interest on the line, and determine whether there are significantly more fields overlapping this point than elsewhere. I've achieved a simpler version of this by finding the centre of the fields and then measuring distances from this point and another arbitrarily defined point, but this approach loses all of the information that comes from the fact that they are spatially extensive.

Can anyone point me in the right general direction? Even knowing the broad class of statistical test I should use for this kind of situation would be a big help!

Thanks!

Comment: I can think of a simple solution for the case of an infinite 'axis', but i assume yours is finite, and I think boundary effects would completely mess up my idea... A bit more info might help: Are the 'fields' all the same length, or similar lengths, or not? How long is the 'axis' compared to a (typical) 'field'?

Comment: In a very simple manner, this can be done as a control chart (just in space not time) -- namely by converting it to number of counts over discrete segments and then calculating deviation form Poissson distribution.

Comment: More information would be helpful (honestly, it's essential).  Either implicitly or explicitly, this problem needs a probability model for the "fields" under a null hypothesis.  For example, we might posit that the fields have fixed length and their right endpoints are uniformly distributed over the possible values (in which case the distribution of the number of overlaps at most predefined points is Binomial).  Bear in mind, too, that you can treat this as a 2D problem (by recording each interval as an ordered pair such as left endpoint and length).

Comment: are the fields all of equal length? if so, there might be an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

A *null hypothesis* of your significance test could be that the number of fields overlapping an $x$ point of the axis ($fields(x)$) comes from the same $k$ distribution no matter which point of the axis we take, i.e. $fields(x) \sim K$, where $K$ may take the values $0, 1, 2, ... \infty$. The *alternative hypothesis* could be that the number of fields at the point of interest ($fields(x_A)$) comes from an other distribution. You have already defined the *test statistic*: the number of fields overlapping ($fields(x)$), and the wording “significantly more” suggests you are thinking in terms of a one tailed test.

When you say “elsewhere” does it mean anywhere along this continuous axis? Or does it mean a number of points along the axis? I will assume the second, and that you have an $(x_1, fields(x_1)), (x_2, fields(x_2)), ... (x_N, fields(x_N))$ sample. I will also assume that the $x_1, x_2, ... X_N$ points are “not too close to each other” - your above figure suggests that the width of the fields is not negligible, thus $fields(x_1) = fields(x_2)$ if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are close to each other.

The significance value of the test is the probability of observing a number of fields *equal to or more than* $fields(x_A)$ under the null hypothesis. Under the above assumptions this is $p \approx 1 - ECDF_K(fields(x_A)-1))$, where $ECDF_K$ is the empirical cumulative distribution function of $K$ estimated using the sample of $N$ points (not including $x_A$).

If you use R all you have to do is use the `ecdf()` function to perform this calculation.